# perl regex faster than c++/boost

Tags: c++, regex, perl, optimization, boost

I wrote a CGI script for my website which reads through blocks of text and matches all occurrences of English words. I've been making some fundamental changes to the site's code recently which have necessitated rewriting most of it in C++. As I'd hoped, almost everything has become much faster in C++ than perl, with the exception of this function.

I know that regexes are a relatively recent addition to C++ and not necessarily its strongest suit. It may simply be the case that it is slower than perl in this instance. But I wanted to share my code in the hopes that someone might be able to find a way of speeding up what I am doing in C++.

Here is the perl code:

```
open(WORD, "</file/path/wordthree.txt") || die "opening";

while(<WORD>) {
chomp;
push @wordlist,$_;
}
close (WORD) || die "closing";

foreach (@wordlist) {
   while ($bloc =~ m/$_/g) {
      $location = pos($bloc) - length($_);
      $match=$location.";".pos($bloc).";".$_;
      push(@hits,$match);
   }
}
```

wordthree.txt is a list of ~270,000 English words separated by new lines, and $bloc is 3200 characters of text. Perl performs these searches in about one second. You can see it in play here if you like: http://libraryofbabel.info/anglishize.cgi?05y-w1-s3-v20:1

With C++ I have tried the following:

```
typedef std::map<std::string::difference_type, std::string> hitmap;
hitmap hits;

void regres(const boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>& what) {
hits[what.position()]=what[0].str();
}

words.open ("/file/path/wordthree.txt");
std::string wordlist[274784];
unsigned i = 0;
while (words >> wordlist[i]) {i++;}
words.close();

for (unsigned i=0;i<274783;i++) {
    boost::regex word(wordlist[i]);
    boost::sregex_iterator lex(book.begin(),book.end(), word);
    boost::sregex_iterator end;
    std::for_each(lex, end, &regres);
}
```

The C++ version takes about 12 seconds to read the same amount of text the same number of times. Any advice on how to make it competitive with the perl script is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/)  a perl compatable regex engine with a `C++` API.

Comment: Also [re2](https://github.com/google/re2) is supposed to be fast at the expense of fewer features.

Comment: Your Perl version could be re-written to be an order of magnitude faster.  There is a Perl approach that would completely eliminate the nesting of loops, and that would play to Perl's strengths.  While I understand the utility of improving performance through using a language that is closer to the metal, one shouldn't neglect the fact that choice of algorithm is often even more important than choice of language.

Comment: @DavidO - that sounds interesting - how would it be done?

Comment: @JonathanBasile : I'll put something up for you to look at in a few minutes.

Comment: @JonathanBasile https://gist.github.com/daoswald/500266d0f23eddf23dc8  (untested).  This plays to the fact that Perl uses Trie optimization for plain-word alternation.  It also means that you no longer have a set of nested loops; just the single `while` loop.

Comment: The reason that the original Perl version didn't perform poorly is that Perl implements Boyer-Moore searching for plain text within a string.  Nevertheless, you are currently passing through your target string potentially 270000 times, whereas my solution passes through the target string one time.

Comment: Some of the C++ responses took a similar approach - but there's no way to match overlapping words with a regex like this, which is one of the things I want my program to be able to do

Comment: In that case I suggest implementing a trie structure with your dictionary.  With such a structure you will be able to walk the target string character by character and generate a list of matches very quickly.  A trie would preserve the goal of avoiding walking the entire word list for every letter in your target string, or the target string for every word in word list.  Spell checkers are a good example of trie structures in use; imagine if every letter you typed required the spell checker to iterate through all 270k words in your computer's dictionary.  Clearly this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'd cut down on the number of allocations:

- use `string_ref` instead of `std::string` where possible
- use mapped files instead of reading it all in memory ahead of time
- use `const char*` instead `std::string::const_iterator` to navigate the book

Here is a sample that uses Boost Spirit Qi to parse the wordlist (I don't have yours, so I assume line-separated words).

```
std::vector<sref> wordlist;
io::mapped_file_source mapped("/etc/dictionaries-common/words");
qi::parse(mapped.begin(), mapped.end(), qi::raw[+(qi::char_ - qi::eol)] % qi::eol, wordlist);
```

In full **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9786110034a3c917)</kbd>**¹

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace io = boost::iostreams;
using sref   = boost::string_ref;
using regex  = boost::regex;

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <typename It>
    struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<sref, It, void> {
        static void call(It f, It l, sref& attr) { attr = { f, size_t(std::distance(f,l)) }; }
    };
} } }

typedef std::map<std::string::difference_type, sref> hitmap;
hitmap hits;

void regres(const boost::match_results<const char*>& what) {
    hits[what.position()] = sref(what[0].first, what[0].length());
}

int main() {
    std::vector<sref> wordlist;
    io::mapped_file_source mapped("/etc/dictionaries-common/words");
    qi::parse(mapped.begin(), mapped.end(), qi::raw[+(qi::char_ - qi::eol)] % qi::eol, wordlist);

    std::cout << "Wordlist contains " << wordlist.size() << " entries\n";

    io::mapped_file_source book("/etc/dictionaries-common/words");

    for (auto const& s: wordlist) {
        regex word(s.to_string());
        boost::cregex_iterator lex(book.begin(), book.end(), word), end;
        std::for_each(lex, end, &regres);
    }
}
```

### Next step

This still creates a regex each iteration. I have a suspicion it will be a **lot** more efficient if you combine it all into a single pattern. You'll spend more memory/CPU creating the regex, but you'll reduce the power of the loop by the number of entries in the word list.

Because the regex library might not have been designed for this scale, you could have better results with a custom search and a trie implementation.

Here's a simple attempt (that is indeed much faster for my `/etc/dictionaries-common/words` file of 99171 lines):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56beec4878c5d54f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;
using sref   = boost::string_ref;
using regex  = boost::regex;

typedef std::map<std::string::difference_type, sref> hitmap;
hitmap hits;

void regres(const boost::match_results<const char*>& what) {
    hits[what.position()] = sref(what[0].first, what[0].length());
}

int main() {
    io::mapped_file_params params("/etc/dictionaries-common/words");
    params.flags = io::mapped_file::mapmode::priv;
    io::mapped_file mapped(params);
    std::replace(mapped.data(), mapped.end(), '\n', '|');

    regex const wordlist(mapped.begin(), mapped.end() - 1);

    io::mapped_file_source book("/etc/dictionaries-common/words");

    boost::cregex_iterator lex(book.begin(), book.end(), wordlist), end;
    std::for_each(lex, end, &regres);
}
```

¹ of course coliru doesn't have a suitable wordlist

Comment: With a 20000 line wordlist, the first c++ version runs in 7.573s, the second c++ version runs in 5.465s _(but it doesn't mark overlapping matches!)_, where the perl version runs in 8m27s. [Note my wordlist and book are identical and probably very different from your use-case, @JonathanBasile]

Comment: when you were testing the perl code, was the text you were searching broken by new lines, or did you search it one line at a time as you input it from a file? I find that perl produces vastly different results if you search a pre-chomped block of text all at once

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response, @Sehe - I was able to get the second working, but I'd definitely like to be able to keep matching overlapping words - unfortunately the first program you've written here gives me a segmentation fault when I try to run it - I can see that the fault is occurring inside the loop, but this code is much too new for me to figure out how to debug it. do you have any ideas of what might be causing the overflow?

Comment: @JonathanBasile Oops that's probably because I didn't guarantee the lifetime of the first memory map long enough. [Fixed it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29738284/revisions)

Comment: Thank you! This is excellent - the first version brought the time down from 12 seconds to two. I'm going to try out a couple of the other suggestions, but I'll probably end up accepting this answer.

Comment: I ended up rewriting the program as a trie as @DavidO suggested - and incorporating the boost elements you used here. its under a second now. Thanks to everyone for their help

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like Perl is smart enough to figure out that you're abusing regular expressions to do an ordinary linear search, a straightforward lookup. You are looking up straight text, and none of your search patterns appear to be, well, a pattern. Based on your description, all your search patterns look like ordinary strings, so Perl is likely optimizing it down to a linear string search.

I am not familiar with Boost's internal implementation of regular expression matching, but it's likely that it's compiling each search string into a state machine, and then executing the state machine for each search. That's the usual approach used with generic regular expression implementations. And that's a lot of work. A lot of completely needless work, in this specific case.

What you should do is as follows:

1) You are reading `wordthree.txt` into an array of strings. Instead of doing it, read it into a `std::set<std::string>` instead.

2) You are reading the entire text to search into a single `book` container. It's not clear, based on your code, whether `book` is a single `std::string`, or a `std::vector<char>`. But whatever the case, don't do that. Read the text to search iteratively, one word at a time. For each word, look it up in the `std::set`, and go from there.

This is, after all, what you're trying to do directly, and you should do that instead of taking a grand detour through the wonders of regular expressions, which accomplishes very little other than wasting a lot of time.

If you implement this correctly, you'll likely see C++ being just as fast, if not faster, than Perl.

I could also think of several other, more aggresively optimized approaches which also leverage `std::set`, but with custom classes and comparators, that seek to avoid all the heap allocations inherent with using a bunch of `std::string`, but it probably won't be necessary. A basic approach using a `std::set`-based lookup should be fast enough.

Comment: In general you can expect arrays to be faster (because of locality). Perhaps you were hinting at a trie (under `1)`)?

Comment: When the lookup set crosses some threshold, I would expect any gains from locality to be insufficient to make up for being bogged down with O(n) search complexity from an array, versus logarithmic complexity one would get from a std::set-based approach.

Comment: Note that a std::vector<std::string> may not necessarily gain much from a vector's locality. The vector itself may be located in one, single clump, but the string data, from each string, itself would likely be scattered throughout the heap, and that's what you end up searching.

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to read the text being searched one "word" at a time because I am matching words in strings of random letters not separated by whitespace or anything else.

Comment: In that case, use std::search(). Or, take the list of words from wordthree, and turn it into one huge /real/ regular expression: (word1|word2|word3...), using the words from the word file.

Comment: I'll try std::search - unfortunately, as @Sehe mentioned above a regex like that wouldn't be able to match overlapping elements.